# How to sort out SSIS Bulk Inset Task error - the device is not ready

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to loop for each csv file in given directory using Foreach Loop Container with Bulk Insert Task in it. When I execute the package I get the error: "[Bulk Insert Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Cannot bulk load because the file "mydirectory:\placeholder\ssis.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 21(The device is not ready.)."."

The file path in SSIS package is correct and the account running the SSIS package has necessary permissions to access the file. The drive is online and accessible and is not used by another process.

Do you have any idea what might cause the error?